# printing json value to file

Tags: python, json

```
   #!/usr/bin/python


import os

import json

import urllib
import urllib2

url = "https://www.example.com"
parameters = {'resource': 'aaaa',
        'apikey': '1111'}
data = urllib.urlencode(parameters)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
json_data = response.read()

with open("test.json") as json_file:
    json_file.write(json_data)

print json_data
```

I dont see I use json again it was before json_data  was used now.

Comment: Why are you loading data from a json file in the first place then? Why do you use `json.load()` **at all** here.

Comment: Isn't it already in a file? What am I missing here?

Comment: And presumably the JSON received is already valid encoded JSON. Why not just write that to a file? No need to encode or decode here.

Comment: Thank you Gp89 and Martijn

i am using linux
it says file not open for writing .. any tips??

Comment: And in a classic example of why you need to include *your error message*: you rebound `json` to a string value, masking the module you imported. Don't use the name `json` for two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have json,

```
with open("test.json", "w") as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Another thing to note here, you should not have a variable named json, because

```
import json
json = 'some string'
json.dumps("{'a':1}")
>> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dumps'
```

if you want a variable named json you can use `import json as j`

Comment: For future reference: use `io.open()` rather than `codecs.open()`; the `io` library is what is used in Python 3 to implement the built-in `open()` function, backported to Python 2, and is far more robust and better engineered than the `codecs.open()` file object.

Answer (score 2):

As Martijn Pieters pointed out, the data is already encoded so you shouldn't need the `json` module at all in this case

You can just write the output to a file

```
json_data = response.read()

with open("test.json" , "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(json_data)
```